# Pip installs module but module is missing

Tags: python, git, heroku, module, pip

I'm new to git, pip, Python, and Heroku (where I'm building my project), so bear with me.

I'm building a Python app on Heroku and decided to use a library from GitHub (specifically https://github.com/arcward/ticketpy). I installed it through `pip install ticketpy` and it worked fine, and later re-installed it manually with `python setup.py install` which also worked fine, but I realized I needed to change some of the library's code for my project. After looking around it seems that the best way to do this would be to set up a repo just for the module, so I could easily deploy it on Heroku. So, that's what I did.

Now, when I run `pip install git+the-url-to-my-git-here`, it works, and pip claims to successfully install the module. There is not a single error. However, if I run `pip freeze` the ticketpy module is not listed. If I run `import ticketpy` from the Python console on Heroku, I receive the message `ImportError: No module named 'ticketpy'`.

I've researched online and tried a number of different things but nothing has worked so far. This doesn't seem like a very common issue either.

If anyone has an idea, I'd really like to hear it; I'm stumped!

Comment: Why would you set up a repo for the module? I would copy the library files into the project folder. (And to change a library is not a good idea anyways)

Comment: @moritzg Isn't that why libraries are open-source in the first place? I needed to change the library to add the functionality I wanted. The reason I set up another repo is to seperate the library from the primary project. I had the library within the project at first but Heroku would not install it properly either.

Comment: This [site](http://www.lonecpluspluscoder.com/2014/12/29/im-strongly-opposed-modifying-third-party-library-code) explains it quite nicely why you shoudn't. Why would you need to install the library? Download the source files and copy them into your project and just use them...

Comment: @moritzg Thanks for the link. The author makes a good point, however I don't feel his argument applies in my case. I _could_ shim the library, however for my particular usage the cost of performance would be too great and I'd inevitably end up modifying the library sooner or later anyway.

Comment: Had you run `pip freeze` in your first case, after you had installed the original library from GitHub or manually? Or was `import ticketpy` working without any ImportError in the first case?

Comment: @IshanAnand Importing ticketpy worked without any issues in the first case, and `pip freeze` did list the library. However, when manually installing ticketpy through `python setup.py install` the library did not work properly; if I tried to access an attribute of ticketpy I would receive an `AttributeError` telling me that the library does not have the attribute I'm trying to access. I had thought this might have something to do with installing it manually which is also why I decided to put the module in its own repo instead.

Comment: @KaiM. I myself run into this problem at times, but in my case it happens because I have two different versions of python (2.7 and 3) and on top of it I use virtual environments for my projects. So, if I run `pip install some_package` (not in virtual env) it installs the package in the global python 2.7 installation libraries and I will not be able to access it in python3 installation or in any virtual env. Similarly, if I run `pip3 install some_package` it installs in the global python 3 installation libraries and I will not be able to access from anywhere else. See if it helps.

Comment: @IshanAnand Thanks! I really appreciate your suggestion. :) Unfortunately it doesn't seem to have made a difference. I tried `heroku run pip3 install git+mygitURLhere -a myappname` and the response is `Successfully installed ticketpy-1.1.1`. However I still get an `ImportError` and ticketpy is not shown when I run `heroku run pip freeze -a appname`. :(

Comment: @KaiM. It seems you got me wrong. I didn't suggest to use pip3 in place of pip. All I mean is: you should check whether your project is using the same python installation where ticketpy is being installed or it is using some virtual environment of its own.
And another area where you might want to look is the `setup.py` file of your version of the ticketpy library.

Comment: @IshanAnand Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. The virtualenv thing occurred to me, but I don't think I'm using one on Heroku. I never made one manually and didn't think it was needed because of the nature of Heroku already isolating applications to individual dynos. Is there any way I can confirm it's not using a virtualenv for my app?

Comment: @KaiM. As you were able to install and run the library without any issues in the first case and if you are following exactly the same procedure for installing and running in the second case then I think we are good here. Another area of concern may be `setup.py` file of your version of the library.

Comment: @IshanAnand Well, this is my first time editing a Python library. I didn't change anything in `setup.py`... is there something I should look for? Peeking in, everything looks ok to me, although I see `url='https://github.com/arcward/ticketpy'` used in `setup(...)`. Not sure if that matters or not.